# View not updating when a message is sent to its view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, model-view-controller

I am having problems updating a view when a message from another class is sent to a `ViewController`.

Basically I have an application with a single window where different custom views will be swapped out for another. I have an `AppController` Class that manages this and works fine:

```
@interface AppController : NSObject

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *ourView;
@property (strong) NSViewController *ourViewController;

- (IBAction)changeView:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender;
- (void)changeViewContoller:(NSInteger)tag;

@end
```

When a new view is swapped out for another, the `ourViewController` property will be updated to point to that view's controller class. Every view controller class will have a method all named the same thing, for example "action". This method is supposed to change something on a view.

So the "start" method in `AppController` class will then call the "action" method on the `ourViewController` property. To do this I used the `objc_msgSend()` method:

```
objc_msgSend(self.ourViewController, action);
```

Here's the View Controller class definition:

```
@interface CountdownViewController : NSViewController

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *label;

- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender;
- (void)start;
@end
```

I placed an `NSLog()` in the "action" method for each `ViewController`, to see if it was working, and it does, however the "action" method is also supposed to change a label's string value, but it does not. If anyone knows why the view is not being updated, that would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the view is held weak?
TRY making it strong if you need to retain that pointer in this class

btw: ..also why do you objc_msgsend.... use performSelector

Comment: I edited by post to show the view controller definition. I also changed the objc_msgsend to performSelector, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: the view is weak... so I ask again: is it held somewhere else? else, it goes away IMHO even if it is the ViewController's view it COULD go away :)

Comment: No, I dont think it's held by anything else. Would making it strong fix this problem?

Comment: yes, when its not held, msgs to the view go to nil... you could set a breakpoint in the debugger

Comment: I changed it to strong, but still no luck... I set a breakpoint, though I'm not sure what it means. It looks like its not connecting to the label: _label NSTextField * 0x0000000000000000.